# What is the right way to work with gmail address book on Android?

Tags: android, sdk, gmail

I'm actively learning Android platform at the moment and decided to write a simple app for myself to manage my gmail emails and contacts. At first I was going to use [Gmail SDK](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) but after reading docs and examples I didn't find any nice way to get all my contacts for my gmail account. After some search I found [Google Contact API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) but it looks pretty complex and over featured for my needs. It seems it can manage any sort of contacts in any possible ways but I just want manage email addresses.

I'd like to keep things as simple as possible and I want use only one API\SDK. It looks quite weird that Gmail SDK allows manage email labels or create email drafts or send emails but there is nothing in it for contacts management. Does anybody know if there is a better way then use both Gmail SDK and Contact API together? May be Gmail SDK can manage contacts some way?

**UPDATE**: I've just tried to get all my emails using Gmail SDK and extract all contacts from them. It worked but this is pretty long and not convenient process.